# How to download a page from GET url using wget

Tags: download, get, wget

I am trying to download the google search results page for Gop primaries results using wget but I am not able to do that ([this page](https://goo.gl/S4hvnM)). But, I noticed that the webpage is getting the data from this file https://goo.gl/KPGSqS which it gets using a GET request.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to download that file with wget? The usual way i do is using `wget -c url` but that is not working. So, any ideas on what i should do for this?
I tried with the user-agent option, but even that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a webpage content (parsed to simple text file or source html code) you could consider using lynx. Download lynx by typing `sudo apt-get lynx` and then you could save the webpage content using `lynx http://your.url/ > savefile.txt`.
You can find how to use lynx in [this](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aczi) page

Comment: I have heard about lynx. But, I am trying to see if its possible with wget. Otherwise i will get lynx

Comment: But what do you need to download? The whole web page (html, css, js, images) or only some information or the visible text?

Comment: Only the data that gets populated in the site. But, the whole website is fine too because ultimately i am going to parse it. If you see the webpage link I have given, you will see that the data is taken from a Json file. I want to get that